# Python weird behaviour List of inherited classes

Tags: python, inheritance

I am building a speech recognition system and for that I build an interface for the commands. They are made up by subjects, verbs, adjectives and wildcards. I implemented it this way:

```
class IWord(object):
    strings = []

    def recognize(self, word):
        return word in self.strings

    def add_synonym(self, word):
        self.strings.append(word)


class Verb(IWord):
    def __init__(self, words):
        for word in words:
            self.add_synonym(word)


class Adjective(IWord):
    def __init__(self, words):
        for word in words:
            self.add_synonym(word)


class Object(IWord):
    def __init__(self, words):
        for word in words:
            self.add_synonym(word)


class WildCard(IWord):
    def recognize(self, word):
        return word is not None & word


class ICommand(object):
    words = []
    parameters = []
```

However I got two classes inheriting from ICommand:

```
class Command1(ICommand):

    def __init__(self):
        self.words.append(Verb(['do']))
        self.words.append(Object(['some']))
        self.words.append(WildCard())

class Command1(ICommand):

    def __init__(self):
        self.words.append(Verb(['lorem']))
```

When I am debugging this part:

```
for command in self.Commands:
    if command.recognize(text):
        return command
```

It seems like command.words contains 'do', 'some', the wildcard and 'lorem'. I don't get what went wrong there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing `words = []`,... in the class definition makes `words` a class-bound variable. Using `self.words` now returns the (initially empty) dictionary defined for the class bound variable which is shared among the derived classes.

Better: Remove definition and add `self.words = []` in the `__init__`s of the derived classes.

Comment: Why the heck is inheritance of classbound variables so badly implemented in python?

Comment: @Curunir I wouldn't say so. If you would e.g. define a `static List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>()` in an `ICommand` class in Java it would behave in the same way.

Answer (score 5):

`self.words` is the `words` attribute of the `ICommand` class (it is not copied when you inherit). So when you append to that, it will append to it on `ICommand`, which will affect every class inheriting from it.

Probably, though, a better thing to do would be something like:

```
class Command(object):
  def __init__(self, words):
    self.words = words
```

Comment: And how would I get it into the child only?

Comment: Add `words = []` to the child classes. But actually, it would probably be better to have a general `Command` class with commands as instances, instead of classes.